# Unable to deploy website with firebase cli

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

firebase.json:

```
{
"hosting": {
     "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ {
      "source" : "**/*.@(otf|woff|woff2|eot)",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
    } ]
    }, {
      "source" : "**/*.@(css|js|png)",
      "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Cache-Control",
      "value" : "max-age=14400"
      } ]
    } ]
 }
}
```

I am unable to deploy static website in Firebase hosting with `firebase deploy` command. Error I am getting is:

```
Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:

Unexpected token ' ' at 3:1
     "rewrites": [
^
```

What exactly is the error?

Comment: It is valid JSON according https://jsonlint.com/. The error makes me think you have an invisible character at the beginning of line 3 in your file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing all the whitespaces, tabs & then tried `firebase deploy`, this time it was successfully deployed.
Still don't know what caused this error. Anyways, thanks SO community.